# Rows are not in line

Tags: html, css

I am working on my project. But I am having problem with structure of my web page. I have made webpage in gridview.

```css
.container {
    width:1000px;
    float:left;
    background-color:red;
 }

.post-loop{
    width:25%;
    float:left;
}

.post-thumbnail {
    float:left;
}

.post-text{
    float:left;
}

.post-text h2{
    font-size:10px;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="post-loop">
        <div class="post-thumbnail">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
            <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my full jsfiddle code https://jsfiddle.net/o39zfegr/

Hope you guys will check it out and will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have not set `height` of items(`div.post-loop`) and using `float` too(which is not recommended nowdays).

So to get rid from this problem you can use `flexbox` as follow.

```css
.container{
  display: inline-flex;
  width:1000px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*float: left;*/
  
}
.post-loop{
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  min-width:25%;
  /*float: left;*/
 
}
.post-thumbnail{
 /*float: left;*/

}
.post-text{
/*float: left;*/

}
.post-text h2{
  font-size:10px;
  font-wight:normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="post-loop">
     <div class="post-thumbnail">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
         <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div class="post-loop">
     <div class="post-thumbnail">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
         <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div class="post-loop">
     <div class="post-thumbnail">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
         <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div class="post-loop">
     <div class="post-thumbnail">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
         <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div class="post-loop">
     <div class="post-thumbnail">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
         <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div class="post-loop">
     <div class="post-thumbnail">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
         <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div class="post-loop">
     <div class="post-thumbnail">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
         <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
        </div>
 </div>
    <div class="post-loop">
     <div class="post-thumbnail">
         <img src="https://i.imgur.com/ZzXsxfp.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="post-text">
         <h2>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</h2>
        </div>
 </div>
</div>
```